# scrollToPosition не работает никак

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-scrollview

```
message_recycler_view.let { recycler ->
    ....
    recycler.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, bottom, _, _, _, oldBottom ->
        if (bottom < oldBottom) {
            recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(oldBottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Скроллится только такой так! Пытался обернуть `scrollToPosition` в `post { }`, `postDelayed()`, `postOnAnimation { }` и т.п. Но работает только `smoothScrollToPosition`... Что делать? Мне нужен прямой переход к `View`.

Comment: а чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @Flippy прямого скролла к позиции, а не smooth

Comment: это ясно, но в каком случае? зачем `addOnLayoutChangeListener`?

Comment: @Flippy разрабатываю чат, когда пользователь нажимает на edittext чтобы ввести сообщение, клавиатура поднимается, а диалог двигается вверх.

Comment: диалог? может список?

Comment: @Flippy да, оговорился. Короче необходимо чтобы список поднимался вверх. Smooth scroll не подходит, а никакие другие скроллы (из тех что я пробовал) не работают.

Comment: блин) суть вашей задачи фатально изменилась) вам надо чтобы при открытии клавиатуры список оставался снизу?

Comment: @Flippy да. Сделать как во всех нормальных чатах: тапаешь на edittext, поднимается клавиатура, последнее видимое сообщение остаётся на месте. Я решил эту проблему (ну почти) через `addOnLayoutChangeListener`. Но не работает никакой скролл, кроме smooth. Где здесь фатальное изменение задачи? Вопрос прежним остаётся.

Comment: эм. в тег активити в манифесте добавь `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` ресайклер трогать не надо

Comment: @Flippy я добавил. Когда клавиатура поднимается, то диалог не подвигается вверх. Нижние сообщения становятся не видны.